# ingress-nginx host redirect in server snippet doesnt work

Tags: regex, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I'm using wildcard subdomain in the ingress and need to redirect any request that contains subdomain with www to non-www i.e.:
`www.randomsubdomain.domain.com` to `randomsubdomain.domain.com`

For this reason I tried to add server snippet to the ingress but it has no effect at all, I have tested my regular expression and it fits my problem but seem to be ignored by my ingress:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
        if ($host ~* "^(www\.)([0-9a-z]+\.domain\.com)$") {
          return 301 https://$2$request_uri;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you just need to add:

```
annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
```